# How to forward url parameters from Nginx to my server's API?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to create "user only" section and I managed to get this far, but I'm stuck. How can I send the requested url to my api?

Here's my Express.js API route, very simple. User visits a link (direct link, embedded links/videos on a page, etc) and tries to view it. I redirect his request to my /api and check whether he's allowed to see it or not. Things that are below work if I remove the :file part and test it with 200 and 403, but I need to be able to check them dynamically.

A clearer explanation is below.
"/" is the generic URL, but /api should be fired only when a visitor tries to access a file, no matter what the file's location / URL is. So what I want to do is, "okay, I'm Nginx and I see that some visitor tries to access some file. let's pass this file's name to Express.js server and let it check whether this user is allowed to see this image or not. If it says 200, I'll allow it. If it's 403, then no."

```
app.get('/api/:file', function(req,res,next) {
  // This part decides what you're allowed to see.
  // Redis database query. Returns 0 or 1. 
  // 1 returns 200, 0 returns 403.
  res.sendStatus(200); // It works, so this part is done.
});
```

But I don't know how to pass the requested url parameter from Nginx to my Express.js app (e.g. image.jpg, video.mp4 in http://localhost/api/:file format) so I can check user's permission against database and return a dynamic response for every file.

Here's my current Nginx config.

```
upstream localhost {
  ip_hash;
  server 127.0.0.1:8000;
  server 127.0.0.1:8001;
  server 127.0.0.1:8002;
  server 127.0.0.1:8003;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
    root images;
    auth_request /api;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://localhost;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
    rewrite ^ /api/$1?$args permanent;
}
```

This should rewrite the file request to the api path. Then you api can decide if let user pass of not.